# SQL Server: Pivot Help / Dynamically Name Columns from a Prefix + Value from Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a rather long SQL query and would like to dynamically build some column names based on the contents of another column. I'm using SQL Server 2012. Is there a simple way to do this without building the *whole* query dynamically? I'm a novice with SQL and I'm looking to do something like:

Going from this table:

```
|A|B|C|D|
---------
 p 1 x l
 p 2 y m
 q 1 x l
 q 2 y m
```

To this table:

```
|A|C1|C2|D1|D2|
---------------
 p x  y  l  m
 q x  y  l  m
```

by pivoting the C and D columns on B and naming them by concatenating some prefix with the values in column B. But haven't been able to find anything that doesn't seem too complex for my SQL skills.

I'd settle for being able to hard-code the columns and then name them dynamically based on the values in column B.

Comment: What do you mean by *"construct a couple [of] column names"*? Showing your table structure and the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: I like to think of column aliases as equivalent to variable names: identifiers you've created which should stay the same. So I would question why you want this, and think about alternative solutions to the real problem. For instance in this example, you could just return two columns from the query, then do whatever you need with them in the calling application / processing.

Comment: I agree with @IMSop. I would call this column `Month_CurrentDate` and then have the application handle it. The only way I can think of to change the column names dynamically would be to build this as dynamic sql.

Comment: Sorry, my example wasn't clear. I was trying to make it as simple as I could and instead just made it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
SELECT  
    CurrentMonthAndYear = CONCAT('Month_', MONTH(GETDATE()))
```

resulting in an output of

```
CurrentMonthAndYear 
-------------------
Month_5
```

as of today (May 2014).